# Play integrity - Get a token in debug mode

Tags: android, google-play-integrity-api

I am building an android app from scratch. So, the app does not exist on Play store yet. I want to use Play Integrity to make sure that the app binary is a genuine one.
Going through the docs of Integrity API ([link to docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup)), it seems that it requires that my app be on Play Store. If so, then I infer that I cannot debug my app with the Play Integrity code in place.
I want to test that everything is working fine by putting breakpoints and debugging it. Any inputs on the same would be helpful.

I have already tried the code sample provided in the Integrity API doc and it gave me an Internal Server Error, asking me to implement exponential backoff and/or open an issue if it is not resolved.

I'm doing this in a Xamarin app. But that should not be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup#apps-exclusively-distributed-outside-google-play), you need to (1) create a cloud project, (2) enable Play Integrity API service via Google Cloud Console and (3) pass that cloud project number via [setCloudProjectNumber](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/reference/com/google/android/play/core/integrity/IntegrityTokenRequest.Builder#setCloudProjectNumber(long)) method when calling the API. Then you can decrypt the token response by calling Google servers as described [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#decrypt-verify-google-servers).